Can't set Dvorak layout with hotkey in Windows?
I have 2 input languages x 2 keyboard layouts set in Windows, and I want to use HotKeys to switch between these, so I set "input language hot keys":

This works for selecting the US layout - alt+shift+2 and alt+shift+4 work.
However, for selecting the Dvorak layout, it does not! alt+shift+1 and alt+shift+3 do not work.
What gives???
Remarks:

The issue seems to be with the layout, not the HotKey. Meaning, if I change the number in the hot keys, it's always the Dvorak layout that do not work.

I've tried using the ctrl+shift shortcuts. Same result.

I'm actually looking for a solution I can use with AutoHotKey. So if there is a solution that skips this part of the Windows config and instead uses a script snippet to change the layout, that's fine (or even preferred).

Whatever the solution, I'd like to also be able to select the layout from the language bar:




Did my answer help?

You could use Set-WinUserLanguageList, with help of PowerShell 5 (it won't work in 7).
First, get the language codes for Dvorak/non-Dvorak layouts with Get-WinUserLanguageList. The IDs are in InputMethodTips property for each language. E.g. for Polish language, Dvorak is 0415:00010409 and programmer's layout is 0415:00000415.
Assign the current list to a variable like $list and modify it by removing the non-used element while leaving only the currently needed one, e.g.:
$inputMethods = ($list | ? LanguageTag -eq pl).InputMethodTips
$inputMethods.Remove('0415:00000415')
$inputMethods.Add('0415:00010409')

Then save the new settings:
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $list -Force

Note: this won't let you change the methods in the Windows taskbar as you are leaving only one. Unfortunately, different order of InputMethodTips achieves nothing, it only changes display order. Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride is just for override.
The only way to work around this that I noticed is to first set only one desired layout with Set-WinUserLanguageList, then .Add() the other one and save the list again, which switches the current one and lets you use both.
Not sure if there's anything better. Perhaps lowel level API function ActivateKeyboardLayout could also be of use, but it's not easy to use in PowerShell, so I'll leave it up to your experiments.
